# Need assistance with html tables and getting php echo's to access database tables

Tags: php, html

So our college assignment involves a number of things right now, but I've currently hit a roadblock.  I've managed to get my page to access the database I have for somethings...but its not displaying all the rows of the database.  I'm not sure what I can do to remedy this.

The page looks like this:
[work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dUDU.png)

Here is my "index.php" coding:

```html
<?php
try
{
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=--------', '-----------', '-------------');
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
  include 'includes/error.html.php';
  exit();
}

try
{
  $sql = 'SELECT title, description, duration, transportation, food, price, image, reservation FROM tours';
  $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Error fetching page: ' . $e->getMessage();
  include 'includes/error.html.php';
  exit();
}

while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
  $tours[] = array(
      'title' => $row['title'],
      'description' => $row['description'],
      'duration' => $row['duration'],
      'transportation' => $row['transportation'],
      'food' => $row['food'],
      'price' => $row['price'],
      'image' => $row['image'],
      'reservation' => $row['reservation']
  );
}

include 'tours.html.php';
```

And here is my tours.html.php page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Portland Historical Tour Options</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Portland Historical Tours have offered three family run tours for decades:  the Downtown Tour, the Growth Tour, and the Landmarks Tour.">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=../project.css>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
      
      <?php include '../includes/header.inc.html.php'; ?>
      <?php include '../includes/navigation.inc.html.php'; ?>
        
    <main>
        <table>
            <span id="caption">Compare Tour Options</span>
            <tr>
                <th id="tourname">Tour</th>
                <th id="tourduration">Duration</th>
                <th id="transportation">Transportation</th>
                <th id="food">Food</th>
                <th id="price">Price</th>
                <th class="reserve">Reserve</th>
            </tr>
        <?php foreach ($tours as $tour): ?>
            <tr>
                <td headers="tourname"><?php echo $tour['title']; ?></td>
                <td headers="tourduration"><?php echo $tour['duration']; ?></td>
                <td headers="transportation"><?php echo $tour['transportation']; ?></td>
                <td headers="food"><?php echo $tour['food']; ?></td>
                <td headers="price"><?php echo $tour['price']; ?></td>
                <td class="reserve"><?php echo $tour['reservation']; ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach ($tours as $tour): ?>
        <h1><?php $tour['title']; ?></h1>
        <img class="image" src="<?php $tour['image']; ?>" alt="Portland Downtown Tour" width="200" height="200">
        <?php $tour['description']; ?>
        <div><?php $tour['reservation']; ?>Reserve</div>
        <br class="clearright">

<?php endforeach; ?>
        
    </main>
      
        <?php include '../includes/footer.inc.html.php'; ?>
      
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Please keep in mind that I'm new to PHP, and this class is for people new to this form of coding.  The instructor wants "simple" solutions" to the issues we face.

The database's table has 3 rows, one of which has links to images present.  These are written in as "images/downtown.png". (This is just one example of course.)

I have tried to rename the links as "../images/downtown.png".

The index.php, and tours.html.php pages are in their own folder.  There is a separate index.php page that is the homepage for the site.  Images, "include" files (like header.inc.html.php) are located in this file.

Comment: Try to reduce your PHP program to a simple script that only does the one thing you are trying to get working. Access the database, execute a query, print all the rows to the console. It's much easier to debug a program like that, rather than trying to see what's going on in a rendered web page. It looks to me that `while ($row = $result->fetch())` should do what you expect but perhaps not.

Comment: Things are displaying, and I've slowly begun to see too many cases where I simply forgot to add an "echo" to things as I continue to work through it.

Now I need to figure out how to get my other images to display and why the <?php echo $tour['reservation']; ?> won't work in this portion of the page:  
     <a href="../reservations.php" class="reserve"><div>Reserve</div>
     </a>
        <br class="clearright">
There's an image that formats to this via the class...but if I add in the php island it messes the whole thing up, so I'm not sure how to add that into it.

Comment: Alright, by persevering at this I managed to figure out the issues I was having and now the problem I was having is resolved.  Thanks for the help anyway folks.  I'm sure I'll be back on here again in the future.